# Which filter will be called first - Middleware Filter or Authorization Filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Between Middleware Filters and Authorization filter, I believe authorization filter is called first but with below code - Its happening the other way around. Middleware filter is called first and then Authorization filter. Why?

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[AuthorizationFilter]
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(TestPipeline))]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [ HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}

public class TestPipeline 
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        //appBuilder.UseMiddleware<Test>();
    }
}

public class AuthorizationFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in microsoft docs, you can check default order of filers and how you can modify it, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: From the link (bolding mine) "Middleware filters run at the same stage of the filter pipeline as Resource filters, before model binding and **after the rest of the pipeline**" so are you sure it's running last?

Comment: this looks like a wrong assumption, you should verify it again and again by yourself. The source code shows that the authorization filters are always executed first.

Comment: Hi @user728630,Please set breakpoint to middleware invoke method and the filter `OnAuthorization` method.You could see that although it will fistly run Configure method,but it does not get into middleware invoke method,it will get into `OnAuthorization` method and last invoke the middleware.

Comment: @Rena you are right!!!! It goes to Middleware > Configure method then the constructor of the injected services are invoked and then Authorization Filter's OnAuthorize method is invoked and then the middlewares are invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe authorization filter is called first but with below code - Its happening the other way around. Middleware filter is called first and then Authorization filter. Why?

You could see that although it will firstly run `Configure` method, but it does not get into middleware invoke method, it will get into `OnAuthorization` method and at last invoke the middleware.